# F# - Organisation of algorithms in a file

Tags: f#, namespace-organisation

I do not find a good way to organize various algorithms. Today the file is like this :

1/ Extraction of values from Excel

2/ First algorithm based on these values (extracted from Excel) starting with
"let matriceAlgo1 ="

3/ Second algorithm starting from the same values 
"let matriceAlgo2 ="

4/ Synthesis algorithm, doing a weighted average (depending on several values) of the 2/ and 3/ and selecting the result to be shown. 
"let matriceSynthesis ="

My question is the following : what should i put before the different parts of this file in order to just call them by there name ? I have seen answers explaining that Module could be an answer but I don't know how to apply it in my case (or anything else if it's not the good answer).At the end, I would like to be able to write something like this :

"launch Extraction

launch First Algorithm

launch Second Algorithm

Launch Synthesis"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually organize files is to have some clear visual separator between different sections of a file (see for example [Crawler.fsx on GitHub](https://github.com/tpetricek/FSharp.AsyncExtensions/blob/master/samples/Crawler.fsx)) and then have one "main" section at the end that calls functions declared previously.

I don't really use modules unless I have a large number of functions with clashing names. It would be good idea to use modules if your algorithm consists of more functions (e.g. `Alg1.initialize`, `Alg1.run`, etc.). Then you could easily switch between using different algorithms using module alias:

```
module Alg = Alg1 // or Alg2

let a = Alg.initialize
Alg.run a
```

If the file is getting longer, then you could also move sections to separate files and use `#load "File.fs"` to load algorithms or functions from a file. In that case, you probably need to use modules, but you can always `open` the module after loading the file.